# Mysql Trigger with IF THEN

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, innodb

My storage is INNODB,
I'm trying to create an trigger with 2 queries in IF statement.
Down you can see the trigger that gives me the error

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER count_delete_videos BEFORE DELETE ON videos
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE counts SET count = count - 1 WHERE name = 'all';

    IF OLD.published = 1 THEN
        DELETE FROM videos_categories WHERE id_video = OLD.id;
        DELETE FROM videos_tags WHERE id_video = OLD.id;
    END IF;
  END;
|
delimiter ;

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= OLD.id;
    END IF;
  END' at line 6
```

This are the 2 triggers that i activate with the first one.

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER count_delete_videos_tags AFTER DELETE ON videos_tags
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE tags SET count = count - 1 WHERE id = OLD.id_tag;
  END;
|
delimiter ;


delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER count_delete_videos_categories AFTER DELETE ON videos_categories
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE categories SET count = count - 1 WHERE id = OLD.id_category;

    IF OLD.id_category <> 20 AND OLD.id_category <> 34 THEN
        UPDATE counts SET count=count-1 WHERE name='english';
    ELSEIF OLD.id_category = 34 THEN
        UPDATE counts SET count=count-1 WHERE name='german';
    ELSEIF OLD.id_category = 20 THEN
        UPDATE counts SET count=count-1 WHERE name='italian';
    END IF;
  END;
|
delimiter ;
```

But this one works perfectly

```
delimiter |
    CREATE TRIGGER count_delete_videos BEFORE DELETE ON videos
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE counts SET count = count - 1 WHERE name = 'all';

        IF OLD.published = 1 THEN
            DELETE FROM videos_categories WHERE id_video = OLD.id;
        END IF;
      END;
    |
    delimiter ;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)
```

How can i make first trigger work? what i'm doing wrong? 
Thx for helping me.

Comment: could you give the if clause twice for each delete statement and see?

Comment: (Except for the counters), do you know that you can have the same behaviour with a Foreign Key constraint (one from each table) to the `video` table, by defining the FKs with `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: yes i know, but on foreing keys triggers in mysql do not activate, so i must delete it with another trigger so this queries activate other triggers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As far as I can tell both triggers are OK, but you might try the following:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER count_delete_videos BEFORE DELETE ON videos
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  UPDATE counts SET count = count - 1 WHERE name = 'all';

  IF OLD.published = 1 THEN BEGIN
    DELETE FROM videos_categories WHERE id_video = OLD.id;
    DELETE FROM videos_tags WHERE id_video = OLD.id;
  END; END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This is what i get -> ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: @P.Alex - And what's your MySQL version?

Comment: @P.Alex, obviously you'll have to delete the other trigger before adding this one.

Comment: i have edited my post. I explained better my problem, please take a look. Thx

Comment: OK, problem solved. The problem was that i had 2 action trigger on the same table.